# WPF how to change text color of a GridViewColumn?

Tags: wpf, listview, datagridviewcolumn

I have this `GridViewColumn`:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"/>
```

Now i want to be able to change this `Column` text color also via code behind.
I try:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Status}" Foreground="Yellow" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

But it seems that the text color is not changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already specifying the celltemplate for each item, you don't need to include the DisplayMemberBinding property, just remove it

```
<GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Status">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Status}" Foreground="Yellow" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: OK that's fine but if i want to change this color for different color for every different item in my ListView ?

Comment: @davidhol You can replace the `Yellow` with any binding logic. The important point is, that `DisplayMemberBinding` has higher priority than `CellTemplate`, thats why the template was ignored in your code (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Can you show me how replace the Yellow with any binding logic ? maybe i can create simple enum and for every enum value change this color ?

Comment: @davidhol if this answers your original question you can mark it as the correct answer, for binding issues you can ask a separate question and we will try to help you.